# Como imprimir em impressora não fiscal pelo tablet

Tags: php, impressora

Criei  um sistema em php para usar em apenas no localhost, mas eu tenho acesso a ele através do tablet via ip / sistema, mas eu queria imprimir  via tablet na impressora não fiscal como eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: Se consegue acesso via IP não há qualquer modificação a ser feita. Se o seu sistema já tem a capacidade e imprimir ele irá imprimir independente de como está sendo conectado. Se ele não tem a capacidade de imprimir a pergunta é totalmente outra, acredito que possa imprimir utilizando as portas COM  e também existe o [`printer_open()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/sr/function.printer-open.php), que é via [PECL](https://github.com/jiminald/PHP-Printer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer fazer seu servidor imprimir o documento, né?

A solução mais simples que conheço é usar um navegador headless - como o [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) e mandar ele acessar a página e imprimir.

No entanto, acho que essa é uma solução mais complicada do que configurar o tablet para acessar a impressora. Se ela não for wireless, você pode usar o [Google Cloud Print](https://www.google.com/cloudprint/) do Chrome, ou então configurar um servidor de impressão.